# Is there a way to automatically update a post when a post is published in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a function that I can use that executes the post to update right after the post is published automatically? If so, could I only target a certain post type as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the save post hook http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post here you can check the post type as well and run what you need to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following hook to modify any post type like this

```
   function change_post_status( $post_id ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        remove_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'change_post_status' ), 99, 2 );

        if ( in_array( $_POST['post_type'], array( 'project', 'event' ) ) ) {

            $user          = wp_get_current_user();
            $allowed_roles = array( 'editor', 'administrator', 'author' );
            if ( array_intersect( $allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) {
                wp_update_post( array(
                    'ID'          => $post_id,
                    'post_status' => 'publish'
                ) );
            }
        }

        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'change_post_status' ), 99, 2 );
    }
}
```